# The SetMarquee function is not working on MultiByte Character Set in C++

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-c++-2013

I am using Multibyte Character Set on my project.

The SetMarquee function is not allowed to access while the character set is MultiByte.

The below function available in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxcmn2.inl**

```
#if defined(UNICODE)
_AFXCMN_INLINE BOOL CProgressCtrl::SetMarquee(_In_ BOOL fMarqueeMode, _In_ int nInterval)
{ ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return (BOOL) ::SendMessage(m_hWnd, PBM_SETMARQUEE, (WPARAM)fMarqueeMode, (LPARAM)nInterval); }
#endif  // defined(UNICODE)
```

I am trying to using below SendMessage function for Marquee style on my code. but it is not working.

```
::SendMessage(m_hWnd, PBM_SETMARQUEE, (WPARAM)TRUE, (LPARAM)1);
```

Could you please help me on this issue.

Thanks!
Vijay Kumbhani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

I need to create a class object of  [**CProgressCtrl**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cprogressctrl-class?view=vs-2015)

```
CProgressCtrl progressCtrl;
LRESULT lResult = ::SendMessage(progressCtrl, PBM_SETMARQUEE, (WPARAM)TRUE, (LPARAM)1);
```

You need to pass **Progress Ctrl** object as HANDLE on SendMessage function.